# How to add an a Array of Strings to a Mongoose Model Array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make a website where users can upload several images and have those images uploaded to Cloudinary and displayed on their post. Everything is working fine except I cannot get the URLs of the images to save to mongoDB or display properly. Here is my code:

```
var imageLength;
var newImage = [];
router.post("/", isLoggedIn, upload.array("image"),function(req, res){
    imageLength = req.files.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < imageLength; i++){
        cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.files[i].path, function(result) {
            // add cloudinary url for the image to the campground object under image property
            newImage.push(result.secure_url);
            req.body.campground.image[i].push(newImage[i]);
        });
    }
    // add author to campground
    req.body.campground.author = {
                id: req.user._id,
                username: req.user.username
            };
    Campground.create(req.body.campground, function(err, campground) {
        if (err) {
            return res.redirect('back');
        }
        for(var i = 0; i < imageLength; i++){
        }
        res.redirect('/campgrounds/' + campground.id);
    });
    return imageLength = req.files.length;
});
```

Here is the model for "Campground":

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   image: [String],
   image_id: [String],
   description: String,
   author: {
     id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
     },
     username: String
   },
   comments: [
      {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "Comment"
      }
   ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Campground", campgroundSchema);
```

And here is where I am displaying their images on their post:

```
<% for(var i = 0; i < campground.image.length; i++){ %>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="<%= campground.image[i] %>">
<% } %>
```

This is the error I am receiving:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/YelpCamp/v10/routes/campgrounds.js:47
            req.body.campground.image[i].push(newImage[i]);
                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/YelpCamp/v10/routes/campgrounds.js:47:38
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/YelpCamp/v10/node_modules/cloudinary/lib/uploader.js:500:51)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Comment: can you please show what `console.log(req.body)` show ?

Comment: @Usman Rana When I console.log(req.body) right before i try to push newImage[i] into req.body.campground.image I recieve this: { campground: 
   { name: 'f',
     description: 'f',
     author: { id: 5aaaf25986f338289129f8ea, username: 'frff' } } }

Comment: there is no `image` property in this. That's why you get error saying `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Comment: @UsmanRana How would I go about adding the image property? I've added it to the model and I've dropped the collection in mongo but I am still receiving the error.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Do you have any advice on how I should continue? Thank you for your help so far.

Answer (score 1):

You are tying to push items into an array with an index. Remove the index and push the items directly into the image object.
Replace 
`req.body.campground.image[i].push(newImage[i]);`
With 
`req.body.campground.image.push(newImage[i]);`

Comment: I now receive the error: "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". This is the same error I had when I tried several other methods to accomplish this task. It's as if it's treating the model as null but the syntax looks correct to me.